# returning const char * from a function in C

Tags: c, api, gcc, constants

In my library I have to return a string to the callers. The string I am returning will be a global array, the intended use from the caller is just to read the string. I don't want them to modify it..

Is this the right way to declare the function..

```
const char * get_some_details();
```

This should generate a warning (tried only gcc) either when the caller assigns the return value to a char * ptr or assigns to const char * ptr, but later tries to modify it.

I am asking because I would expect functions like getenv() to return const char *. But it returns char *. Is there any gotcha in returning const char * ?

Comment: getenv returns char* because the buffer pointer that is returned is not constant.  It contains your result string after calling getenv, but that same buffer can be changed by future calls to getenv, setenv, or unsetenv

Comment: So the following usage of getenv() is not correct ?name=getenv("NAME"); id=getenv("ID"); use name & id. The second call to getenv() could overwrite whatever name was pointing to before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Returning `const char*` is exactly the right thing to do in these circumstances.

Many older APIs don't use `const` since they pre-date the introduction of `const` in C90 (there was no `const` before then).

Comment: Note that this rationale doesn't apply to the example of getenv in the original post.  getenv takes a const char* and returns a char* http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/getenv.html

Answer (score 2):

That is the right way to do it.

Many standard library functions take or return `char *` when logically it should be `const char *`, for historical reasons: pre-C89, there was no `const`; post-C89, their type signatures could not be changed without breaking application code.  As a general rule, do *not* use the standard library as a style guide; it is very old and contains many things that are no longer considered good practice.  (*cough* `gets`)

Comment: Fortunately, `gets` was removed in C11.